# No such module 'module X' on Xcode 12.2 only on Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

I have recently updated my Xcode to version 12.2 and my macOS to version 11.0.1 Big Sur . My project will successfully when I select my actual device but when I select a Simulator it starts showing this error

> No such module as 'X'

Of course rebuilding and deleting DrivedData and pod install ... not worked.
where is the problem?
it has no issue runnig on my actual device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this piece of code at the end of your PodFile and you are good to go

```
  post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

Comment: Still facing this issue, do you have any other workaround?

Comment: if this one doesnt work , try to run on actual device or build under generic device , or if you really insist on building for simulator run on rosseta